# Python, compare n by m numpy array with n sized numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, compare

Im doing a programming project and I´m hard stuck for some reason.

```
gradeList = [-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]

    for i1 in range(np.size(grades,1)-1):
        for i2 in range(np.size(grades,0)-1):
            for i3 in range(len(gradeList)-1):
                if grades[i1,i2] != gradeList[i3]:
                    print(grades[i1,i2])
                    print(i1,i2,i3)
                    print("This is an error"+str(grades[i1,i2]))
                else:
                    print("FINE")
```

I´m trying to check each value in the n by m array for each value in my gradeList and eventually I want to print the position of the grades in the n by m array that are not in the gradeList. I get the following error code:

```
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3
```

My grades array:

```
 grades = np.array([[  7.    7.    4. ],[ 12.   10.   10. ],[ -3.    7.    2. ],[ 10.   12.   12. ],[ 12.   12.   12. ],[ 10.   12.   12. ],[ -3.8   2.2  11. ],[ 20.   12.6 100. ],[  4.   -3.    7. ],[ 10.   10.   10. ],[  4.   -3.    7. ],[ 10.   10.   10. ],[ 10.   10.   10. ],[ 12.   12.   12. ],[ -3.   -3.   -3. ],[ 20.   12.6 100. ]])
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your grades definition

Comment: Oh yeah I see, but I just put that there to let you guys know what numbers I am using.. I´ll change it

Answer (score 0):

You've swapped the definitions of `i1` and `i2`, which causes the error you're getting. Here's how to fix your code:

```
for i1 in range(grades.shape[0]):
    for i2 in range(grades.shape[1]):
        for i3 in range(len(gradeList)):
            if grades[i1,i2] != gradeList[i3]:
                print(grades[i1,i2])
                print(i1,i2,i3)
                print("This is an error"+str(grades[i1,i2]))
            else:
                print("FINE")
```

In the above code `grades.shape[0]` is equivalent to `np.size(grades, 0)` in your original code. The `grades.shape[0]` is the more commonly used idiom.

Additionally, I've removed all of the `-1` adjustments from the definition of your ranges. If you have those there it will prevent your loops from reaching the last values in your arrays. The behavior of `range` is that it will stop one value before it reaches the maximum value you set it to.

For example, `list(range(len(gradeList)))` will return the complete set of indices of `gradeList`:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

whereas `list(range(len(gradeList - 1)))` will omit the last index:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies there:

```
# i1 => [0,1]
# i2 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
# i3 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When you call `grades[i1,i2]` you can have `grades[0,3]` and its out of bounds, since that axis has three elements.

I guess the solution is to change  `grades[i1,i2]` to `grades[i2,i1]` where it appears (three times).